# I'm creating an array in C which calculates the product of an array

Tags: c, arrays

It needs to return NAN if the product is 0. At the moment it's calculating some weird values and I'm not quite sure whats wrong.

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double array_product( double arr[], int n ) {
    double product = 1;

    for(int i = 0; i <= n; i++){
        if(isfinite(arr[1]) == true){
            product *= arr[1];
        }
    }

    if(product == 1){
    return NAN;
    } else {
    return product;
    }
}


void call_function( const char * label, double x[], int count ) {
    double prod = array_product( x, count );
    printf( "%s\n", label );
    printf( "\tInput data:\n" );

    for ( int i = 0; i < count; i++ ) {
        printf( "\t%d\t%f\n", i, x[i] );
    }

    printf( "\tProduct = %f\n\n", prod );
}

int main( void ) {
    double x1[] = {0};
    call_function( "Count == 0", x1, 0 );

    double x2[] = { NAN, +INFINITY, -INFINITY };
    call_function( "No finite values", x2, 3 );

    double x3[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };
    call_function( "Several finite values", x3, 7 );

    double x4[] = { 2, M_PI, NAN, 3, INFINITY, 4 };
    call_function( "A mix of finite values and infinities", x4, 6 );

    return 0;
}
```

The values calculated look correct but when I do the manual calculations the values are much larger.
Thank you in advance for the help

Comment: I don't understand why the index is always `1` in `arr[1]` inside function `array_product()`. Aren't you trying to loop over all the elements and multiply them?

Answer (score 1):

You wrote that you have to return `NAN` if the product is 0 but your code returns `NAN` if the `product` is 1.

Now pay attention that you multiply all the time only the element at position 1 and the loop should iterate till `n` but not including.

```
double array_product( double arr[], int n ) {
    double product = 1.0;
    bool multPerformed = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(isfinite(arr[i])){
            product *= arr[i];
            multPerformed = true;
        }
    }

    if(product == 0.0 || !multPerformed){
        return NAN;
    } else {
        return product;
    }
}
```

Also note that comparing `double` using `==` oprator is very dangerous.

Comment: had to change the if (n==0 || product == 0.0) to == 1.0, and now it works! Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @BobFisher3 but if your input array is {1.0, 1.0, 1.0} it will return NAN. Please see my latest edit.